# Uncaught TypeError: undefined in removeCookie

Tags: jquery

I check and the cookie is there but I got an error of `Uncaught TypeError: undefined`, below is my code:

```
$('#logout').click(function(){
  $.removeCookie("fb_userId");
});
```

Comment: how did you check that cookie is there?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar resources tab chrome tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that script loading order is wrong. Try doing:

- include jQuery
- include jQuery cookie plugin
- move your code in `$(document).ready(function () {...});`

You code will be:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logout').click(function(){
      $.removeCookie("fb_userId");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I use "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"

Comment: @user3522742 Since this issue was solved, you can mark the answer as correct and ask another question for your other problems.